# store multiple song in mpplayer that are being fetch from database having song persistent id

Tags: iphone, mpmediaitemcollection, mpmediaquery

i am trying to store multiple song in mpplayer that are being fetch from database having song persistent id..but only single song is being added .here is what i am doing

MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:persistentId forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
    [query addFilterPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *mediaItems = [query items];
    //this array will consist of song with given persistentId. add it to collection and play it
    MPMediaItemCollection *col = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:mediaItems];
    ///....
    [col release];

thanks in advance

Regards
devon smith

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the PersistentID represents more that 1 track? I use a Persistent ID for each separate track in the album.